# how to separate these two boundary in this image?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

I have segmented an image using watershed algorithm. Now this image contains many objects. I want some selected objects for further analysis. My question is how to remove unwanted objects in this image. The input image itself is noisy. What is the best way to do?

input image

[image]

I want output image should be like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you recognise which object is unwanted? Do you have coordinates of each unwanted object or you decide it by some kind of criteria?

Comment: No i don't have coordinates of unwanted objects. I can say unwanted objects are far separated from group of wanted objects. Also unwanted objects should be in periphery side and may have large area/volume.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your desire from the algorithm, correctly, I would suggest this method:

Do a `floodFill` (filling all wholes). After that you had some big filled objects and some small objects too. based on the sizes of these objects (which can compute with connected component or `findcontour` algorithms) pick the biggest one then find the convex hull of this big object. This procedure, gives you a mask that could be multiplied to the input image you displayed here (the output of watershed). The result would be your final image (something like the one you displayed here).

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the unwanted objects are separated by a minimal distance d.

Make another bitmap. For each pixel, take all pixels which are closer than d/2. If any of these pixel is white, make the corresponding pixel in the auxilliary bitmap also white. Else make it black. After you pass all pixels, each separate object will have a continuous reperesentation in the auxilliary bitmap. So you can use floodfill to cut the wanted objects.